# Supplementary questions to an already existing question

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I often find an answer to my question, but only partial. For instance, people make a nice suggestion on how to modify something in LaTeX, but do not specify how to make the return to default, original values. Then I'd like to just add a simple additional question without opening a new subject.

E.g. I've found an answer on how to do something with `srcbook.cls`, and would like to know how to do that with the standard, `book.cls`, if possible. Is it possible to add a related question ? If not, please consider this, as it would be highly practical!

P.S. What tag (which is obligatory) suits a general question like this one!?

Comment: Standard procedure at this point is to open a new question, with a link to the original, possibly identifying the new question as a "follow up".  I think that works quite well.

Comment: In case the answer is trivial (for example if the `scrbook` thing works out-of-the-box with `book`), you can simply test it and mention it as a comment to the original answer. If you open a new question, and the two questions have the very same answers, they are likely to be marked as duplicates.

Comment: For the PS. question: such "general questions like this one" are usually asked here on meta.tex.stackexchange.com, it is the very purpose of this "alternate" site.